# How to configure the server part or frontend to avoid the error not found 404 when I run ng build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I ask this question because I'm not sure if from the frontend or backend is the solution to my problem.

Basically, I have the problem that when reloading the page in a different route from the start `"/"`, I get the error `"not found 404"`, I have seen some possible solutions such as include a "hash" but for SEO issues I can not do it. I have also seen that there are configurations to solve this problem, but these configurations are in apache servers or in ISS.

My application works fine while using angular-cli with `ng serve`, but when I run

```
ng build --prod --base-href=./ and --deploy-url=./
```

the routes do not work when I reload the page.

For example:

```
http://localhost/my_folder_compilated/programa/detalle-programa/5cf7d27faa8e180017211754    --> 404 not found!
```

I need to deploy it on a Heroku server or in its absence any that works on nodejs.

How can I solve this problem?

```
// this is the route that I have in my app.routing.ts
{path: 'programa/detalle-programa/:programaId', component: 
DetalleProgramaComponent},
{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
```

**Note**

I think the solution is in the backend. I'm using nodejs (express), but I can not fix it.

**Update**

I am using this code and works well well for my routes,

```
const distDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
const file_path = path.join(distDirectory, req.url.split('?').shift());
console.log(file_path)
if (fs.existsSync(file_path)) next();
else res.sendFile(path.join(distDirectory, 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(distDirectory));
```

except for this one:

```
localhost/programa/detalle-programa/5cf7d27faa8e180017211754
```

and in console this is the route that I a receiving:

```
   ...public\programa\detalle-programa\runtime.366eb317d0165de30d51.js
```

obviously it does not exist and it marks an error in my files

**Update 2:**

The folder on my server heroku is:

```
public --> here my files, and the index.html
```

and my index.html is:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.51e30e538d2560c1a9e9.css">
</head>


<body>
    <app-root ></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime.a5dd35324ddfd942bef1.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.3eb7881d3a00da6c675e.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts.dd86f002a5aef1b13f0f.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.23ac360bc829b49bc07d.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem that happens to me is that all the requests I get that I'm doing are returning my index.html file, that's why the promises of my services can not be resolved.

Comment: If you don't want to use the hash, then you have to handle it server-side using a back-end like nodejs/python.

Comment: @MunimMunna Yes, exactly. as I said in the question I'm trying to configure this from nodejs to upload it to heroku

Comment: Try, removing dot in ./

Comment: @Mahi if I do it this way, from the index.html it does not detect the other files.

Comment: Try this way , ng build --prod --base-href= /myApp/  <=== configure myApp route in backend

Comment: server.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/myApp'+ '/index.html');
})   this is your idea?

Comment: In your html file js file urls start with a leading `/`, but css file url does not, this is unexpected. Is your code on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following settings in your express `index.js` file, set the `distDirectory`
to your `dist` directory.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

const distDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    const file_path = path.join(distDirectory, req.url.split('?').shift());
    if (fs.existsSync(file_path)) next();
    else res.sendFile(path.join(distDirectory, 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(distDirectory));

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

**Update:** using above code your routes are working, but you are getting 404 for
JavaScript and CSS files. The reason is:

```
// Never use a leading dot in base-href
ng build --prod --base-href=./
                            ^^
```

Few examples of valid base-url:

```
website url: http://localhost/my_folder_compilated/
base url:    /my_folder_compilated/

website url: http://localhost:4200/public/
base url:    /public/
```

**N.B:** You don't need to set `--deploy-url=./`, use `base-url` only.

Comment: I have updated the question with your help, but it does not work. what is the split (?)

Comment: `.split('?').shift()` takes `image.jpg` from `image.jpg?_=435252344`, it takes the filename without the query strings. The code above works for me for url `localhost/programa/detalle-programa/5cf7d27faa8e180017211754`.

Comment: I feel honored with such a good response. I do ng build --prod --base-href =. / because if I do not, my index.html will never find the files. but I just followed your recommendation prod --base-href = / and I am having same problem..

Comment: if I have a navigation from the index.html everything works. if I charge in this route: ...programa\detalle-programa\ it works, but if I charge in this route: localhost/programa/detalle-programa/5cf7d27faa8e180017211754 I have the problem that I told you about (...programa\detalle-programa\runtime.366eb317d0165de30d51.js).

Comment: ng build --prod --base-href=/public/ ?

Comment: Please see the valid base-url examples, your base-url depends on your website url. In no circumstances you gonna need to set base-url with a leading dot, if your js/css files are not loading, there's only one possible reason, your base-url is not correct.

Comment: You are very kind, I appreciate your help. what you say makes a lot of sense, locally it works for me. but on the server no. Excuse my ignorance, but I will try to explain what I have done. 1- I am using `your code`. 2- I have executed `ng build --prod --base-href =/`

Comment: 3- until this point works for me `locally`. but on the server I get the problem that in my `get requests` the `index.html` file is always returned. on the server I have everything inside a folder called `public` and within `public` I have all my code, the `index.html` and the `other libraries` (you can see the code that I put of my html, and you are right I forgot to put the correct route to my css). I do not know what step I'm missing, or should I put in my `base-href=/public` ?. I hope you can help me, and I hope I will not bother you anymore.

Comment: (I can not upload the code for reasons of confidentiality)

Answer (score 2):

You have to redirect all routes to your Angular app's `index.html`. This is because your frontend handles the navigation, not the backend.

If you are for example using express, you can have a catch-all route:

```
server.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

Comment: @yavg It is requesting a compiled javascript file that does not exist, right? The file is referenced in your `index.html` which might be out of date?! Try rebuilding your Angular application and check that the files listed in your `index.html` are actually there.